# Problem with Cats FlatMap in my Tagless Final class

Tags: scala, scala-cats, tagless-final

I have the following class:

```
class MyBot[F[_] : FlatMap]
```

In this class I have a function:

```
private def handleCallback(): F[Boolean]
```

In my understanding this should work:

```
handleCallback().flatMap(..)
```

But it throws: `cannot resolve symbol flatMap`

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of *Mon Calamari* did not fix my problem, but when checking `FlatMap` on the suggested Blog I spotted:

`import cats.implicits._` which I missed - and fixed my problem - everything stayed the same.

Comment: If you do not want to import a lot of implicits. You only need `import cats.syntax.flatMap._`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to summon an instance of `FlatMap[F]` and use its methods to flatMap:

```
class MyBot[F[_]](implicit F: FlatMap[F]) {

  def handleCallback: F[Boolean] = ...

  def flatMapCallback: F[Boolean] = F.flatMap(handleCallback) { bool => 
    ...
  }

}
```

More details in great blog from eed3si9n: http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/